# Best possible "generic" implementation of Comparator?

Tags: java, comparator, comparable, timsort

We recently had some troubles migrating from Java 6 to 7 because we have tonns of Comparator implemented in a way they not fullfill the Comparable contract and throw a Exception using the new Timsort algorithms.

**Edit**: Input from  User Marco Forberg and class signature

I now found a Comparator many of the others are extending from, the compare method looked like this:

```
@Override
public int compare(final T o1, final T o2) {
    return 0;
}
```

And i changed it to this in the hope i cover most of the cases:

```
 @Override
public int compare(final T o1, final T o2) {

    //Case: XOR check for either s1 or s2 being null
    if(o1 == null ^ o2 == null){
        return (o1 == null) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    //Case: both are null
    if(o1 == o2){
        return 0;
    }

    //Case: Its Comparable!
    if(o1 instanceof Comparable && o2 instanceof Comparable){
        Comparable c1 = (Comparable) o1;
        Comparable c2 = (Comparable) o2;

        return ObjectUtils.compare(c1, c2);
    }

    //Case: We don't know (ran for years this way)
    return 0;
}
```

The class signature looks like this:

```
public class MyComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
```

While `ObjectUtils` is from the Apache Commons 3 and provides a null-safe compare method (I know the time i call this none of the both objects can be null because of the previous checks and i could use c1.compare(c2) as well)

Did this improve the behavior of the "Base"-Comparator? (which i assume)
and i am right that this would basically cover the Comparable contract since the value 0 is now returned for non-comparable Objects?

Comment: change your "both are null" case to `o1 == o2` that works if both parameters are the same object as well if both are null

Comment: Thank you for the input, since this is how Apache Commons is doing it this way i will edid my post.

Comment: @R.J: Thank you for corrections... do you know how i can make spaces to format the code and improve readability? (When i create the question it looks all good... then i post it and it gets trimmed this way)

Comment: You can see a orange colored *?*, above the question box, just below the title, on the right hand side. You can use that to help you out with the formatting. As far as your code is concerned, it looks pretty neat to me. No worried about it

Comment: @R.J: Very many thanks for your feedback and again for improving my question by your edits. I will read the formatting informarmation this weekend to try to fullfill the high lvl of quality of stackoverflow in the future. Have a great day!

Comment: Which exception is thrown with the old implementation?